# .htaccess redirect 301 mistakes to wrong URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've gone from WordPress to Joomla on one of my sites. I want to redirect the old links to new ones in my .htaccess file. This is what I have done:

```
Redirect 301 /vereniging https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/wie-zijn-we
Redirect 301 /vereniging/media-berichten https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/wie-zijn-we
Redirect 301 /vereniging/bestuur https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/wie-zijn-we
Redirect 301 /vereniging/maandblad-ucea https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/verenigingsblad-ucea
```

etc. etc. (there are more than 50 Redirect 301 lines) in the .htaccess file. What happens is that the old url http://www.chjc.nl/vereniging redirects to https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/wie-zijn-we (so far, so good), but all the following lines go wrong: they end up on my 404 error page.

I suspect the problem lies in the fact that on the old site there was a page called http://www.chjc.nl/vereniging and then a number of related pages that had URLs starting with http://www.chjc.nl/vereniging i.e.

```
http://www.chjc.nl/vereniging/media-berichten
http://www.chjc.nl/vereniging/bestuur
http://www.chjc.nl/vereniging/maandblad-ucea
```

I tried adding /index.php

```
Redirect 301 /vereniging/index.php https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/wie-zijn-we
```

but that didn't help. I'm sure there are many Apache / .htaccess specialists out there who can help.

Anyone?

Thanx,

Thom

Comment: Do all the old urls redirect to the same new URL?

Comment: No, they don't. I guess it would have been a whole lot easier. 
The old links have the short version let's say `/main-folder/` and then some `/main-folder/longer-address/` Anub Hava's answer below is helping me in the right direction. Tomorrow I'll to finish it completely.

Answer (score 2):

Better use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` to target precise URL patterns using regex. `Redirect` directive works on using `startsWith` paradigm.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/vereniging(/media-berichten|/bestuur)?/?$ https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/wie-zijn-we
RedirectMatch 301 ^/vereniging/maandblad-ucea/?$ https://www.chjc.nl/chjc/verenigingsblad-ucea
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Or use `curl -I http://www.example.com/old-target` to check without browser redirect caching.

Comment: Definitely Patrik. I always test using command line `curl` only.

Comment: Hi there, This is going in the right direction, thanx a lot! Could you explain what the wild cards stand for? I mean `?/?$` As I said there are more than 50 lines and it gets more complicated. If you want I could add all 50 lines, but I'd rather spare you that, especially since I want to learn how it works, so I can do it myself next time. 

Perhaps I should add a few examples: 
`^/vereniging/regios`
`^/vereniging/regios/noord-oost`
`^/vereniging/regios/zuid`
`^/vereniging/regios/zuid-west`

Comment: I used `^/vereniging(/media-berichten|/bestuur)?/?$` to match your first 3 rules. It will match `/vereniging` and `/vereniging/media-berichten` and  `/vereniging/bestuur`. Also all 3 URLs also allow an optional trailing `/` i.e. `/?$`